# Install new facebook template for asp mvc4 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm struggling with creating a new facebook mvc4 web application.
I've registered a new facebook app and I've done everything correctly, I think so at least.

When I launch my application it gets redirected to facebook like it should do, but facebook displays an error.

I searched the error keywords and a got an answer that my facebook template from VS2013 is giving the error because the facebook apl has changed.

> Could not convert string to integer: installed. Path
>   'data[0].permission', line 1, position 34.

So my question is, how can I install a new updated, functional facebook template and where can I find it?

[image]